# SOCKS Proxy testing

Tags: networking, proxy, socks

I have made a socks proxy that runs Socks4 and socks5. However I don't know how to test udp and binds, as every application and site uses connect.

Side question is socks4 only used for domain resolving, I'm not talking about 4a and 4c.